# I am not able to navigate from homepage to loginpage after clicking on sign out button

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, google-api, firebase-authentication

I have created sign in application with google authentication using flutter. I am not able to enter into homepage after clicking on Login button, and I had once logged in to homepage, when i create the authentication code in the loginpage itself. but now I am using another file for authentication named auth.dart and I have called the function from there to loginpage and homepage(where signout button is there). please help me and tell me how to go to homepage and from homepage vice versa

```
//Here is my code for loginpage.dart

//button for login with google
 RaisedButton(
                child: Text('Login with Google'),
                color: Colors.orange,
                textColor: Colors.white,
                elevation: 7.0,
                onPressed: () { authService.googleSignIn();
                }
              ),
```

Here is my Code for authentication in auth.dart

```
class AuthService {
  final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn=  GoogleSignIn();
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  Observable<FirebaseUser> user;
  Observable<Map<String, dynamic>> profile;
  PublishSubject loading = PublishSubject();

  AuthService() {
    if(_auth.currentUser()!= null) {
      print('Please Sign in');
    } else {
      googleSignIn();
    }

  }
  Future<FirebaseUser> googleSignIn() async{
    loading.add(true);
    //GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = await googleSignIn.signIn();
    GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
    GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;
    final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
      idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
      accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
    );
    final FirebaseUser user = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
    print("User Name: ${user.displayName}");
    assert(await user.getIdToken() != null);
    final FirebaseUser currentUser = await _auth.currentUser();
    assert(user.uid == currentUser.uid);
  }

  void SignOut() {
    _auth.signOut();
  }
}

final AuthService authService = AuthService();
```

and Finally here is my code for Homepage.dart where SignOut button is

```
MaterialButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    authService.SignOut(); 
                  },
                child: Text('Log Out'),
              )
```

I have tried `Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('landingpage');` 
but it says undefined name 'context'

please help me out

Comment: from where you try to navigate ? please add some more information if possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
RaisedButton(
     child: Text('Login with Google'),
     color: Colors.orange,
     textColor: Colors.white,
     elevation: 7.0,
     onPressed: () { 
          authService.googleSignIn().then((firebaseUser){
               Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('landingpage');
          });
     }
)
```